# Using Xcom to push a value from PostgresOperator and pull it in PythonOperator

Tags: airflow

I want to push a result of a query "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table_name>" from a PostgresOperator and push it to a PythonOperator which is a pythonCallable and the value is to be used in a python function. How can I use XCom in this? I tried different ways through net but everytime I get an error that undefined variable in python function.

```
def <python_function_name>():
  """variable to be used in this code."""

python_airflow_step = PythonOperator(
   dag=dag,
   task_id = <task_name>,
   python_callable= <python_function_name>
   ???
)

postgres_airflow_step = PostgresOperator(
   dag=dag,
   task_id = <task_name>,
   sql= ?
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get records from the PostgresOperator. It hasn’t been designed for that which makes sense. Don’t forget that Airflow is an orchestrator, not a processing framework. Your data should be processed in a tier tool and not directly inside Airflow .

If you truly want to get some data from your Postgres database, you will need to use the PostgresHook.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had a similar problem and I wrote an new Operator based for a MsSqlOperator.

So if I translate my code to the PostgresOperator, I think it should look like this.

```py
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
from airflow.providers.posgtres.hooks.postgres import PostgresHook

class ReturningPostgresOperator(PostgresOperator):
    def execute(self, context):
        hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id=self.postgres_conn_id)
        return hook.get_first(self.sql, parameters=self.parameters)
```